# How does one include the magnetic scalar potential in the electromagnetic four-potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

The electromagnetic four-potential is typically written as $$A_{\mu}=(\phi,\vec{A}),$$
where $\vec{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential, and $\phi$ is the electric scalar potential.

Should I want to use the magnetic scalar potential, $\phi_M$, instead of $\vec{A}$, what would the expression of $A_\mu$ look like?

Comment: It doesn't work. The magnetic scalar potential is an aid to simplifying some calculations, but it is not part of any 4-vector as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Helmholtz decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), for any solenoidal field
$$\mathbf B = \nabla \times \mathbf A$$
on some bounded domain $V\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, then

$$ \mathbf A(\mathbf r) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_V d^3 r' \frac{\nabla' \times \mathbf B(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} - \frac{1}{4\pi} \oint_{S} dS' \ \left(\hat n' \times \frac{\mathbf B(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}\right)$$

where $S$ is the surface enclosing $V$ and $\hat n'$ is the outward-facing normal vector.

For magnetostatic situations in the absence of any current density (in which $\nabla \times \mathbf B=0$, and so $\mathbf B = \nabla \phi_M$) it follows that

$$ \mathbf A = \frac{1}{4\pi} \oint dS' \left(\hat n' \times \frac{\nabla' \phi_M(\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}\right)$$

Explicitly writing $A_\mu$ in terms of $\phi_M$ is unpleasant, but it is possible, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds convincing... although, as you say, writing it might be indeed unpleasant...